# Unable to use create-react-app - unexpected string in JSON at position 66

Tags: reactjs, terminal, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a react app using `npx create-react-app`. I'm getting this error message in the terminal and I have no idea what it means or why I'm getting it. It was working fine earlier.

````
test $ npx create-react-app my-app`
npx: installed 99 in 4.831s

Creating a new React app in /Users/timothyegart/Desktop/test/my-app.

error An unexpected error occurred: "/Users/timothyegart/Desktop/package.json: Unexpected string in JSON at position 66".
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.19.1
error An unexpected error occurred: "/Users/timothyegart/Desktop/package.json: Unexpected string in JSON at position 66".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/timothyegart/Desktop/test/my-app/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /Users/timothyegart/Desktop/test/my-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.```
````

Comment: can you please show your packages.json file

Comment: My guess is you have a dangling comma, but please share the contents of your `package.json` file.

Comment: thanks for helping - how do i show access/show you the file?

Comment: Copy/paste should work.

Comment: Looks like it's on your desktop: "/Users/timothyegart/Desktop/package.json". But I see what you mean, like it's not getting generated properly. If the file exists can you update question with it? It's a plain text file so it should open in any text editor/IDE/etc..

Comment: AHHH, I found it.  I had a hanging comma.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: Nailed it! So was it created malformed or is there still an issue?

Comment: It was created malformed!

Comment: Does it consistently repro? Repro in another working directory? What version of CRA are you using?

Comment: I meant it wasn't malformed - no longer an issue.  I just had to delete a comma i must have added last night.